# Could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to

Tags: typescript

I have a few namespaces which all contains a same name nested class for example named `R`. I'd like to make a generic function as a factory which could: instantiate a new instance of `R` if I only pass the namespace as a parameter so I got here:

```js
namespace A {
  export class R {
    public i = 0;
  }
}

namespace B {
  export class R {
    public s = '';
  }
}

type Input = typeof A | typeof B;
function Test<T extends Input>(v: T): InstanceType<T['R']> {
// Type 'A.R | B.R' is not assignable to type 'T["R"]'.
//  'T["R"]' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'A.R | B.R'.(2322)
  return new v.R();
}

const instance = Test(A);
```

My purpose was to make the `Test` function to auto infers and returns `T['R']`. However, I just got an error which shows above.

Why the `v.R()` was inferred as `'A.R | B.R'` and wasn't been narrowed based on T?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBJBvAUEpEAeMA9gE4AuS8ANiFFEgEobY5IwCuARpQJbxLdIAvEgAMAbmYBfTNMyhIsBMgBCTHPiJkK1WgzUt2XXkjrCA5GYk5ps0gE8YyAJLB25YfceEAZqiQAfJE8IHyRlCW82YHhSbkJgJAAVaFIAHkTcPFIIYAATOhc3AD4ACgA3AC4kgEoqlyhSEGiIRIcIdIBtM3ozAF0i-WIIUjZiBOAIAHckMoA6ehLqiWl4eIb+YAamxCEklJKUJaA)

Comment: Why would v.R be narrowed? You probably meant to use `InstanceType` on T["R"] too since T["R"] is the class constructor type, not the instance type (maybe even something like this https://tsplay.dev/WyQ6AW).

Comment: Your return type is incorrect to start with: `T['R']` is the type of `v.R`, not the type of an instance of that.  You'd need `InstanceType<T['R']>` here, and then you get the issue where TS can't follow arbitrary generic type operations, especially involving conditional types.  What you *can* do is just make `T` the instance type to start with, possibly as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaZrym).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I updated the post to add the `InstanceType` but code is still not working. How can I correct it?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the link. It looks like what I was looking for. Could you please explain the reason what's the issue and how it get fixed? That would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot really do much analysis on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  Such types could turn out to be just about anything once the type parameters get specified, and so the type checker mostly just gives up.  It treats such types as *opaque*, and cannot generally verify whether any specific value is assignable to them.  Since [the `InstanceType<>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) is [implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3c221fc086be52b19801f6e8d82596d04607ede6/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1629) as a conditional type, and since `T` is a generic type parameter, the type `InstanceType<T["R"]>` is such an opaque type and the compiler will complain about any `return` statement where the value being returned isn't already known to be exactly `InstanceType<T["R"]>`.

Furthermore, when looking at operations involving values of generic types like `new v.R()`, the compiler will often make the simplifying assumption that the generic type parameter can be widened to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  So in `new v.R()`, `v.R` is first widened to type `Input["R"]`, a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181)), and then `new v.R()` becomes the union type `A.R | B.R`, which is not identically `InstanceType<T["R"]>` and the assignment fails.

Essentially the compiler is just not clever enough to follow your logic here.

---

One way to proceed is to avoid generic conditional types by refactoring.  Instead of having `T` be the type of the `v` argument, make it the intended instance type being returned:

```
function Test<T extends InstanceType<Input["R"]>>(
  v: { R: new () => T }
): T {
  return new v.R(); // okay
}
```

Since `v` is of type `{R: new()=>T}`, the compiler knows that `v.R` is of type `new()=>T`.  That's a single [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that takes no arguments and produces a value of type `T`.  So `new v.R()` is known to be of type `T`, and the function compiles.

Since you apparently care about not passing in arbitrary objects with a constructable `R` property, but specifically allowing only `A` and `B`, then we

I have constrained `T` to `InstanceType<Input["R"]>`.  This evaluates to the union `A.R | B.R`.  So the function will only allow inputs with an `R` property that constructs instances of `A.R` or `B.R`.  Of course that's not necessarily important, since the function will happily work on any arbitrary object with a zero-arg constructor at its `R` property, so you might want to just leave `T` unconstrained, depending on the use case.

Okay, let's test it:

```
const instanceA = Test(A);
// const instanceA: A.R

const instanceB = Test(B);
// const instanceB: B.R
```

Looks good.  And the following is rejected, if `T` is constrained:

```
// function Test<T extends InstanceType<Input["R"]>>(⋯
class X { x = 1 }
const instanceX = Test({ R: X }); // error!
```

but if `T` is unconstrained, then it is accepted and produces an instance of the appropriate type:

```
// function Test<T>(⋯
class X { x = 1 }
const instanceX = Test({ R: X }); // okay
// const instanceX: X
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBJBvAUEpEAeMA9gE4AuS8ANiFFEgEobY5IwCuARpQJbxLdIAvEgAMAbmYBfTNMyhIsBMgBCTHPiJkK1WgzUt2XXkjrCA5GYk5ps0gE8YyAJLB25YfceEAZqiQAfJE8IHyRlCXloOEQkADlCR31vNmB4Um5CYCQAFWhSAB5s3DxSCGAAEzoXNwA+AAoANwAuHIBKFpcoUhBUiGyHCEKAbTN6MwBdGv0cYghSNmIs4AgAdyQGgDp6OtarJGkceEyu-mAunpjhXK66lF2ZTDlwKKUkAGFj0mIQbmXypJSaQyWWuBSK+FKFSqZ26vX6jny1TYpCGACJ6KjJvVmDhmhgGC1lmsdkIpkUDkh2jlpkhZvNFkgiestjs9rJmEcYadzr00Fc8rd7jgAPTCiifbmwxAoFooLaPQ4S348xCqfk3ZRCpCi8Vc5VSiDKFrKeUcnR0AAa+LwQiQAEZ9hylTCLhArerSHV0ASkFbJLttWKIMRiCQAIQ4R7s5KpdKZHJ5QrY3Etb30QmrJAkwRkx1UopYGZzBZLTObbb3dmck76118hM3O4SHXV8i13my02tyWutUNz2a5ti7vt1XGrvm33W20O6Qjl29d39r0+v33FvOlVuloWoA)

Comment: `Essentially the compiler is just not clever enough to follow your logic here.` Does that means the information here is actually enough for infering, if as a human, but the compiler just wasn't able to do that? So the solution is to make the situation simpler to help compiler the work?

Comment: More or less, yes.